The No Slip/Slip Condition for Rotating/Rotating and Translating Bodies
Consider a sphere of radius $r$ that is rolling on a rough surface, where its translational velocity $v$ is equal to $\omega r$, where $w$ is the angular velocity of its rotation. In this case, I understand that the sphere does not slip across the surface.
But I just wanted to clarify some of this theory further and check if my understanding of it is accurate:
Is it correct to say that if $v\neq \omega r$, slip will occur, where if $v<\omega r$ the sphere will rotate "too fast" while moving along the surface at a slower rate and where if $v>\omega r$ the sphere will slip? Does the direction of this rotation matter?
The most important thing I wanted to check is the following:
We know that no slip occurs if $v=\omega r$, so can this be extended to an accelerating system by taking the derivative with respect to time on both sides to give:
$\frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{d\omega}{dt}r$ i.e. $a = \alpha r$, where $a$ is the acceleration of the sphere and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration relating to its rotation?
Finally, from this, can we say that if $a\neq \alpha r$, slip will occur?
Any help would be highly appreciated, and do correct me if I've got anything wrong or written anything in an unclear manner. Thank you in advance.


Is it correct to say that if $v≠ωr$, slip will occur

yes

where if $v<ωr$ the sphere will rotate "too fast"

yes

where if $v>ωr$ the sphere will slip?

yes

Does the direction of this rotation matter?

yes

Finally, from this, can we say that if $a≠αr$, slip will occur?

yes

$\dots$ can this be extended to an accelerating system by taking the derivative with respect to time on both sides $\dots$ - yes

In the first three examples on the left, the friction force to the left, $F$ reduces the speed of the centre of mass of the object to the right whilst the the torque the frictional force produces about the centre of mass increases the clockwise angular speed.
Note that for the left hand case, if the anticlockwise angular speed is large enough the linear velocity of the object will reverse and it will start moving to the left.
In the example on the right, the friction force to the left, $F$ increases the speed of the centre of mass of the object to the right whilst the the torque the frictional force produces about the centre of mass decreases the clockwise angular speed.
